# Inlining in Java

Tags: java, jvm, inlining, inline-method

In C++ I can declare a method "inline" and the compiler is likely to inline it. As far as I understand there is no such keyword in Java.

Inlining is done if the JVM decides to do so? Can I influence this decision somehow?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A couple of the other answers have suggested that only final methods can be inlined - this is not true, as HotSpot is smart enough to be able to inline non-final methods so long as they haven't been overridden *yet*. When a class is loaded which overrides the method, it can undo its optimisation. Obviously making the method final mean that's never required...

Basically let the JVM do its job - it's likely to be a lot better at working out where to inline than you are.

Do you have a situation where you're convinced that the JVM isn't doing a good job? Assuming you're using HotSpot, have you tried using the server version instead of client? That can make a *huge* difference.

Comment: Actually HotSpot can inline methods (speculatively) even if it is overridden, and call the method virtually for objects that are not of the expected type. Server HotSpot will even inline two different versions of a method (bimorphic inlining).

Comment: @Tom: Mind if I include that in the answer?

Comment: well, I definitely had cases were hotspot did not inline and manual inlining lead to factor 5 improvement in performance of a core processing loop.

Answer (score 6):

Although the java compiler can do inline (for short early-bound methods) the **real** inlining will be done by the JIT compiler.
The JIT (HotSpot) compiler will be able to,even, inline *virtual* methods.
The best way to interact with it is to write a simple and concise code.
Most likely, code that uses Reflection will not allow for inlining.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you give any evidence for the Java compiler (as opposed to the JÍT compiler) inlining method calls?

Comment: *"Most likely, code that uses Reflection will not allow for inlining"* — [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102000/cannot-change-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) seems to have it the other way around, is it?

Answer (score 5):

*'In C++ I can declare a method "inline" and the compiler will inline it'*... or not. The compiler is free to make the function inline or not and you cannot really affect the result. It is only a hint to the compiler.

In Java there is no such thing, the compiler (and later the VM while performing optimizations) can decide to 'inline' the method.

Note that *final* methods have greater chances of being inlined (the compiler cannot inline non-final methods, as they may be overwritten in derived classes). With modern VM, a similar optimization can be made at runtime. The VM will flag the type (so it can perform type checks) and will inline the code. Only if the check fails, it will fall back into the original unoptimized polymorphic method call.

Comment: Important point! "inline" does not force the compiler to inline your method in C.

Comment: Thx, you are right, I forgot that "inline" is a suggestion to the compiler!

Comment: You can sometimes force the compiler to inline, but that's complier specific: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934529/c-inline-functions-using-gcc-why-the-call

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Java compilers can NOT decide to inline methods  - only the JIT compiler can.

Comment: "the compiler cannot inline non-final methods, as they may be overwritten in derived classes)" - completely false statement. The JIT compiler can and does inline non-final methods if it hasn't been overridden at run time yet.

Comment: @SteveKuo: That was the reason for *final methods have **greater** chances*, maybe it is not clear enough in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Inlining is more likely to happen if the method in question is:

- short
- final
- not dependent on any long, non final methods

As these are the only circumstances where the JVM can be certain of the effects of the call.

Comment: `final` doesn't make any difference for HotSpot.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Interesting, could you elaborate?

Comment: @MCEmperor Subject to change, but it just checked whether any loaded classes overrides the method.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A {
    final int foo() { return 3; }
}
```

Given this class, any call to foo() can be replaced with the constant "3". Any Java1 virtual machine can do this, because the **final** keyword explicitly dictates that it isn't possible to have a subclass that overrides "int foo()".

Inlining the method provides the following benefits at the call site:

- No method call
- No dynamic dispatch
- Possible to constant-fold the value, eg. "a.foo()+2" becomes 5 with no code executed at
  runtime.

*In the past, programmers often inserted the **final** keyword for exactly this reason*. Or to better facilitate inlining and increase execution speed, they would combine many smaller methods into one larger method. But in many ways, such techniques defeat the entire facility of modularization and reusability built into the programming language.

Modern JVM, like the Java HotSpot VM is able to inline the class without the **final**. keyword**.

(http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Networking/HotSpot/inlining.html)

Comment: A keyword(to advise the compiler) to make a function call inline must have made more sense given that for sake of readability you sometime break certain computation in several function while at the sametime you want those call to be made inline at runtime to save a lot of function-call overhead.

Comment: Answer by @David Rodriguez below make sense. If inline keyword is meant to be ONLY a HINT to the compiler, then it is better be left to the compiler and trust it, that it will inline the call wherever possible without our advice.

Answer (score 2):

Read this for Inlining behavior.
http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/thinkinginjava/comparingc++andjava.html

It says Final methods can be Inlined but not always.

Comment: The fact that that article implies interpretation as the norm - "there are just-in-time compilers appearing at this writing" suggests it's hardly up to date. VMs have come a long way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the JVM decides to do it, it can. Ways to influence include setting the method as static or as final.

Of course, the most important thing about it is that the structure of the method needs to be inline friendly. Short helps, but most importantly it needs to only use its local variables and its parameters, no fields, and minimal method calls to other methods in the same class.

However you should not look to do such optimizations prematurely, you could actually be making things worse (because you could be short-circuiting other potential optimizations). The JVM will sometimes realize that a method can be inlined without these hints.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing a normal function and final function(which is said to be inline by JVM), I have seen that there is no performance improvement between them. Maybe overhead of function call is already very low.

Note: I used box blurring algorithm for evaluating performance.