# Shorter way to check for null with parseDouble?

Tags: java

`amountStr` is a value that occasionally contains a double value represented as a string.

I want to use `Double.parseDouble` to read it into a `double` variable: `amountDbl`.

```
this.amountDbl = Double.parseDouble(amountStr);
```

It seems to throw a `NullPointerException` if `amountStr` doesn't have a value.

Does this mean I have to write a check like this every time?

```
if(amountStr!=null)
    this.amountDbl = Double.parseDouble(amountStr);
```

Because I have so many statements like this in my code, I'm hoping for a more concise way of doing this check (or avoiding it).

Comment: If some operation on an object throws a `NullPointerException`, what more do you expect to do than checking the object for null?

Comment: The computational time to check for `null` must be thousands of time shorter than the parsing part.

Answer (score 12):

You get a conciser expression if you use the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:):

```
this.amountDbl = amountStr != null ? Double.parseDouble(amountStr) : 0;
```

or write your own utility function

```
public static double parseDoubleOrNull(String str) {
    return str != null ? Double.parseDouble(str) : 0;
}
```

and do

```
this.ammountDbl = parseDoubleOrNull(ammountStr);
```

Note however that this doesn't protect you against malformed doubles. If this is a concern I suggest you go with the utility function and do something like this:

```
public static double parseDoubleSafely(String str) {
    double result = 0;
    try {
        result = Double.parseDouble(str);
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you're after concise code you could even do

```
import static pkg.UtilClass.parseDoubleSafely;
```

Comment: You can also mark the utility function as *final*. This would enable inlining.

Comment: If it is static it can't be overridden anyway.

Comment: I like the suggestion of a utility function so that the OP's files aren't littered with tests for null.

Comment: @Alexey - According to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159087/inlining-in-java being final makes no difference to inlining, at least in HotSpot.

Comment: @CPerkins Yes, I have to agree. Moreover `static` methods can't be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a wrapper class for the amount that handles this test in the constructor/factory or handles a null amount as a special case, eg the [Null option pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)
- Use a Java utility library like guava that implements a [Optional](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) (expected to come in Guava r10)
- Google Guava has a `T firstNonNull(T first,T second)` that can be used as `Double.parseDouble( Objects.firstNonNull(amountStr,"0") )`
- (Switch to  Scala and use the  [Option Pattern](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2007/08/martians-vs-monads-null-considered.html))

Answer (score 0):

Why not initialize it beforehand to a "default" value?

```
String amountStr = /* some default value */
```

Then, when you use the variable, check for that special case.

```
if (amountDbl != /* some default value */)
    //parse it
```

Comment: I'm wondering what to use in place of `default` to make typing `amountStr != default` appear more elegant than `amountStr != null`.  It certainly doesn't change the structure of the code at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could always surround it with try/catch or use a ternary operator (as aioobe did)

```
try{
   this.amountDbl = Double.parseDouble(amountStr);
} catch (Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ah, catching runtime exceptions especially NPE doesn't sound really good, does it?

Comment: If the try-block contains one single call to a static method I think it is fine to catch NPEs.

Comment: Well, you can always narrow it down to just catch(NullPointerException npe) {...} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {...}

Answer (score 0):

It's not much better but you could do:

```
this.amountDbl = Double.parseDouble(amountStr==null ? "" : amountString);
```

Comment: Bad idea since `Double.parseDouble("")` throws a NumberFormatException.

Comment: Well, I assumed that this code would already be wrapped in a try..catch anyway.  You need to handle NumberFormatException in case amountStr doesn't have a valid number in it.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(amountStr==null ? "0.0" : amountString);` might be a better idea.

Comment: I guess it depends on how you want to handle invalid doubles.  Do you want to default to some number or do you want to bail out or maybe log, skip, and continue.  There are a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a couple of years late to answer this question. The NumberUtils Class in org.apache.commons.lang3.math package has a method createDouble that does what you are asking for(https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#createDouble-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 0):

I was initializing an object and needed to convert from String to Double and ran in to null values from String.

A a = new A(value1, value2 == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(value2), value3....);

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

Double.parseDouble(str.isEmpty()?"0":str);

or

Double.parseDouble((str==null||str.isEmpty())?"0":str);

Comment: You should really not recommend this, it is not readable and it does an unnecessary parse-call in the case of 0. This way it is not a good piece of code