# Cannot change static final field using java reflection?

Tags: java

I recently stumbled upon [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) and tested polygenelubricants' `EverythingIsTrue` class, works fine, `System.out.format("Everything is %s", false);` prints `Everything is true` indeed. But when I change the code as

```
public class EverythingIsTrue {

    public static final boolean FALSE = false;

    static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        setFinalStatic(EverythingIsTrue.class.getField("FALSE"), true);
        System.out.format("Everything is %s", FALSE);
    }
}
```

it prints

```
Everything is false
```

Does anybody know why? Does setFinalStatic actually work or not?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When accessing primitive static final fields, the Java compiler will assume that the value is a constant and inline the value instead of generating code that accesses the field. This means that the compiler will replace with the reference to the `FALSE` field with the value `false`. If you use reflection to access the field, you will see that the value of the field has actually changed.

This will not work for non-primitive fields, as the value of an object reference can not be inlined at compile time.

Comment: Which is exactly the same answer as mine - only with more words!

Comment: @dty it looks like it are infinite more words even ;)

Comment: I deleted my answer as yours had been accepted and mine wasn't adding any value - only brevity! ;-)

Comment: Actually, it doesn't *assume* that it is constant.  The compiler *analyses* the expression to see if it is a "constant expression" as defined by the JLS.  If it is, then it evaluates it and inlines the value.  For instance, `public static final boolean TRUE = "".isEmpty();` will NOT be inlined, even though it is obvious to you and me that the value is always `true`.  The reason is that that expression is not a "constant expression" according to the JLS.

Answer (score 25):

You can avoid compiler inlining by making the value a result of a method call, even a dummy one.

```
public class Main {
    // value is not known at compile time, so not inlined
    public static final boolean FLAG = Boolean.parseBoolean("false");

    static void setFinalStatic(Class clazz, String fieldName, Object newValue) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiers.setAccessible(true);
        modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, newValue);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", FLAG);
        setFinalStatic(Main.class, "FLAG", true);
        System.out.printf("Everything is %s%n", FLAG);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Everything is false
Everything is true
```

Comment: This is awesome! Using a generic method you can make a dummy method for non primitives `static <T> T placeHolder() { return null; }`

Comment: @dit It is console output, so it should not be formatted as if it were source code.

Comment: @mc-emperior I think the idea was to highlight the `true` and `false` to make the difference more clear.