# How do I set a primitive private static final field in a class with private constructor using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, reflection, intellij-idea, junit, powermockito

I'm trying to set a `private static final` field in a class with `private` constructor for a JUnit test. When I boil the code down to its basics, I get the following:

```
public class Foo {
    private static final boolean FLAG = false;
    private Foo() { /* don't call me */  }
    public static boolean get() { return FLAG; }
}
```

My tests looks like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareEverythingForTest  // Whitebox fails without this line
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        Whitebox.setInternalState(Foo.class, "FLAG", true);
        assertTrue(Foo.get());
    }
}
```

And here is an excerpt from my POM file:

```
<junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
<powermock.version>1.5.4</powermock.version>
<mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
```

When I put a breakpoint on `return FLAG;`, I can clearly see that `FLAG` was set to `true` in IntelliJ's debugger. Yet the test fails with an `AssertionError`.

Any ideas what to do to make this work?

**Update:** using reflection doesn't seem to work, either:

```
@Test
public void testGet_usingReflection() throws Exception {
    setField(Whitebox.invokeConstructor(Foo.class), "FLAG", true);
    assertTrue(Foo.get());
}

public static void setField(Object targetObject, String fieldName, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class clazz =  targetObject.getClass();
    Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
    modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(targetObject, value);
}
```

The `setField()` method is one I have available through an internal library. Unfortunately, it produces the same result: `AssertionError`

**Update 2:** Getting completely rid of PowerMock doesn't help much, either, apparently:

```
@Test
public void testGet_usingReflectionWithoutPowerMock() throws Exception {
    setField(Foo.class.getDeclaredField("FLAG"), true);
    assertTrue(Foo.get());
}

public static void setField(Field field, Object value) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
    modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, value);
}
```

For this, I even removed the PowerMock annotations from the class level...

I've also posted this question to the [PowerMock mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/powermock/9AaCaKJfGCI/tx0HPn0WDQAJ) now.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No. I ended up changing the constant from using primitive `boolean`to object wrapper `Boolean`, I think.

Comment: I am using Wrapper Integer but it's not working for me. :(

Comment: Check your generated classes in your target directory using a [decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) to verify what's actually going on, and if the compiler [inlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281347/how-do-i-set-a-primitive-private-static-final-field-in-a-class-with-private-cons?noredirect=1#comment54866343_33508845) the value somewhere. If not, [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide (as much as necessary and as little as possible) detail of your classes and tests. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar thing to test, but the only difference was that my static final variable was an `Object` rather than primitive type. And indeed changing `boolean` to `Boolean` makes it work.

```
public class Foo {
    private static final Boolean FLAG = false;
    private Foo() { /* don't call me */  }
    public static boolean get() { return FLAG; }
}
```

Also I would recommend using `@PrepareForTest(SomeClass.class)` where `SomeClass` has static final field rather than `@PrepareEverythingForTest` because if it's big project it may take some time prepare everything.

Comment: I found the answer why reflection can't change the primitive field's value here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102109/2018047 The value is inlined by the compiler, so there is a constant in the code wherever there is a reference to it. I can change the field using reflection, it is just never referenced at runtime... Still not sure why PowerMock, which manipulates byte code, can't do it, though.

Answer (score 0):

WhiteBox.setInternalState does not work with class with a final field.

You can use Reflection to resolve this issue:

```
static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {  
  field.setAccessible(true);  

  Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");  
  modifiersField.setAccessible(true);  
  modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);  

  field.set(null, newValue);  
}
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=324

Comment: Well, according to [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/powermock/SfQygHwGeGY/SKsigfkiFS8J) in the PowerMock group, `Whitebox` should be able to set `final` fields, provided the class is prepared for test. I also tried reflection, with pretty much the same result (i.e. not wroking). I updated the post accordingly.