# How in unit test set private static field to default value before each tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I am using Spring and Java 11. I used non-static fields in my @Service, but I got a critical error on Sonar Qube saying:

```
"Members of Spring components should be injected"
```

So I changed these fields to static.

Now in my unit tests, I test my service, which is declared in this way:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private myService myService;
```

But if I change a static field in one test, the value is reflected in the other test. How can I set all private static fields on values which are initialized on start:

```
private static Integer count = 1;
private static boolean isChecked = true;
```

**Edit:**
I can add to my class I have also filed it with annotation @Autowired

```
@Autowired
private MySecondService mySecondService;
```

in test class, I have this object with annotation @Mock

```
@Mock
private MySecondService mySecondService;
```

So if a solution will be to use @Before or something like this and initialize this object in this method. I also need to initialize all Mock objects.

Comment: regression to the rescue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102000/cannot-change-static-final-field-using-java-reflection

Comment: @Stultuske that is about static and final. This field is only static and not final. So compiler won't inline it.

Comment: Never ever do something like _InjectMocks_ with
_Spy_. It is not supported by Mockito, on the contrary Mockito discourages this combination.

Comment: What about creating setter methods and marking them @VisibleForTesting? Sonar will give an alert if these methods are called outside tests.

Comment: @dimirsenZ I don't like this solution where I have to create a public method to be able to test something. But If I don't find other solution maybe I will do it.

Comment: The problem is not the static, but the fcat you are keeping state in your singelton service. Unless that is really needed on the class/instance level yu should inline the variables in the methods where needed.