# C/C++: Is there a performance penalty for using the adapter pattern?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, adapter

I am using [a high performance/parallel graph library](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/stinger/index.php) written in C in a C++ project. It provides a struct `stinger` (the graph data structure) and operations like

```
int stinger_insert_edge_pair (struct stinger *G,
                          int64_t type, int64_t from, int64_t to,
                          double weight, int64_t timestamp) { .... }
```

Most of the time, however, I do not want to specify timestamps or weights or types. Default parameters would be nice. Also, an OOP-like interface would be nice: `G->insertEdge(u, v)` instead of `insert_edge_pair(G, u, v, ...)`.

So I was thinking of creating an **adapter** class looking like

```
class Graph {

protected:

    stinger* stingerG;

public:

    /** default parameters ***/

    double defaultEdgeWeight = 1.0;


    /** methods **/

    Graph(stinger* stingerG);

     virtual void insertEdge(node u, node v, double weight=defaultEdgeWeight);

   };
```

The method `insertEdge(...)` simply calls `stinger_insert_edge_pair(this->stingerG, ...)` with the appropriate parameters.

However, performance is a crucial aspect here. What is the performance penalty associated with using such an adapter class? Should I expect degraded performance compared to using the "naked" library?

Comment: Very hard to tell without profiling. Other than that the general aspects of good coding still remains.

Comment: "Other than that the general aspects of good coding still remains. " Is using such an adapter good coding in your opinion?

Comment: Why adapt with virtual functions? Do you want to provide different kinds of adapters? A simple adapter that forwards calls to the c api in inlined methods should have nearly zeor overhead.

Comment: Using a specific design pattern for a specific scenario is a design issue, can you substantiate the reason why you are using a specific pattern and not another ? Performance issues are to be asked latter.

Comment: I thought that such a class would provide the more concise and more OOP interface which I wanted and would allow me to provide default parameters (call it "adapter pattern" or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your insertEgde just forwards the call to stinger_insert_edge_pair there would (most probably) be no difference in code generated between the plain call to stinger_insert_edge_pair and g->insertEdge (provided you remove the virtual specifier). 
Comparing the assembly code that is generated through the plain call and adapter call would give a fair input on the overhead your adapter is bring in.

Does insertEdge have to be virtual? Are you planning to have subclasses of Graph? But again, cost of virtual function call is almost negligible compared to real cost the function execution itself.

Comment: In this case, performance is more important than extensibility, so `insertEdge` does not have to be virtual.

Comment: If you are too skeptical I suggest you remove it. But I would rather remove it because I know I would never derive and override and not state performance as the reason.

Answer (score 1):

A virtual function *usually* can't be inlined, so there is the same amount of overhead from a function call (pushing parameters on the stack, possible disruption to the pipeline and cache, etc). In practice, a routine function call is very fast--on the order of clock cycles. The only way to know for sure whether this is appropriate is to **test** on your own application.

Comment: So you would recommend making methods non-virtual when performance is desired? This would enable inlining, but non-virtual function calls do not have a significant overhead if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @cls Yes, don't use virtual functions unless *forced* to do so. There's almost always a compile-time work-around.

Comment: Even virtual functions can be inlined *if* the compiler can statically  (i.e., at compile time) determine the type for which the function will be invoked. Note I'm not saying this is common or expected, only that it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use trivial `inline` methods, compiler should inline them at point of calling, so there won't be any performance penalty. However note, that you shouldn't use virtual functions for this.

Comment: Could you define "trivial inline methods"?

Comment: The problem is that at least gcc **may not** really inline function even if it marked as `inline`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934529/c-inline-functions-using-gcc-why-the-call
Also, there is an `always_inline` for gcc, but that's non-standard feature.